# '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character error after replacing illegal chars

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I am parsing xml and when the xml is in a bad format it skips using the xml document and goes through regular text parsing. I replace all illegal xml characters but I am still getting this error appear randomly;

'<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character

Why do xml errors still crop up if you take the xml text put in a text file and parse it regularly using string parsing or regex stuff. I can see the content after replacing illegal characters and it still won't load into a xml doc and still gives errors in the regular parsing.

cleanup methods:

```
Private Shared Function replaceIllegalXMLChars(ByVal item As String) As String

    Dim returnValue As String = item
    returnValue = returnValue.Replace("&", "&amp;")
    returnValue = returnValue.Replace("""", "&quot;")
    returnValue = returnValue.Replace("'", "&apos;")
    returnValue = returnValue.Replace("<", "&lt;")
    returnValue = returnValue.Replace(">", "&gt;")

    Return returnValue

End Function

Private Shared Function replaceIllegalChars(ByVal state As String) As String
    'remove any hexdecimal characters like &#x19; and &#x0;
    state = Regex.Replace(state, "&\#x([0-9A-F]{1}[0-9A-F]{0,1});", " ")
    'remove any hexdecimal characters like &#19; and &#0;  (no x's)
    state = Regex.Replace(state, "&\#([0-9A-F]{1}[0-9A-F]{0,1});", " ")
    state = Regex.Replace(state, "0xFFFF", " ")
    'added on 3/19/2008 to fix a non-encoded character issue, mostly for LJ
    state = Regex.Replace(state, "&nbsp;", "&amp;nbsp;")
    'mark as completed
    Return state
End Function
```

calling function content

```
         Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        _html = replaceIllegalChars(_html)
        _html = replaceIllegalXMLChars(_html)
        _html = checkUnicode(_html)

        ' now load the file as a xml file
        xdoc.LoadXml(_html)
```

some times I get the error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1,
is there any clear cut methods of cleaning up xml and parsing it.

if I were not to format the xml but just take the raw text and parse it, then why do xml errors still crop up, should it not just be considered to be text and if not then is there anyway other than manually to go through the doc and find all errors in tags etc and correct it.

Comment: Can you post the offending XML? Your error is indicative of a < living within a string somewhere; whereas < can only be used as portion of a tag as I am sure you are aware as you are replacing < with &lt;

Comment: unfortunately I cannot but in response to your suggestion...since I figured the raw xml must be bad with unclosed tags somewhere...if I were not to format the xml but just take the raw text and parse it, then why do xml errors still crop up, should it not just be considered to be text and if not then is there anyway other than manually to go through the doc and find all errors in tags etc and correct it.

Comment: Fixing broken XML shouldn't be your job. Whoever is sending the bad XML should simply open it in XMLSpy or Visual Studio or whatever XML editor, find and fix the problems.

Comment: @John Saunders, I wish that worked in the 'real' world :P

Comment: @Tony: it works if you make it work. There cannot be thousands of versions of standards, or else they're not standard, and we're all stuck fixing broken XML. There is no excuse for not following standards which have been in place for over a decade! Besides, the sender of the XML may not know there's a problem - it might simply be a bug!